# remove ViewController from memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I hope to load an ViewController and do something then unload (viewDidUnload) it from memory.

```
 if (self.vViewController5.view.superview==nil)
 {

  ViewController5 *blueController = 
  [[ViewController5 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View5" bundle:nil];

  self.vViewController5 = blueController;

  [self.vViewController5 setDelegate:self];
  [blueController release];
 }



 [self presentModalViewController:vViewController5 animated:YES];
```

later, call

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but I found that dismissModalViewControllerAnimated does not trigger the event viewDidUnload of Viewcontroller5.

I try function release but it caused program collapse.
I also try removeFromSuperView but it does not trigger the event ViewDidUnload neither.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` is only called when your application receives a memory warning, and the view is not active.  It's generally used for releasing retained views (including IBOutlets).  You can use `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` to respond to a dismissal (`dealloc` will also be called eventually, but not necessarily exactly when the view is dismissed).

Comment: Is there a way to unload viewcontroller from memory?

Comment: When you dismiss a modal view controller, it will be released and usually deallocated (unless you've retained it somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

A dismissed UIViewController will not trigger the viewDidUnload, as you have discovered. However it will trigger [viewWillDisappear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidDisappear:) method, if that suit your needs.